# Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess doesn't make the CSS tranisition to work

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if the Title is a little vague.

This is my view in which I want to create a transition when left or right buttons clicked. However, the transition doesn't work because as far as I understood the `OnSuccess` callback happens before rendering the page. So I can not see the transition effect. I couldn't find any workaround to fix it :(

```
      <script>
            function show() {
                document.getElementsByClassName("comment-item-panel")[0].style.right = 0;
            }
        </script>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Comments", null, 
    new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "comm", OnSuccess = "show()" }
, new { @class = "comments" }))
        {

                <button type="submit" name="page" class="vertical-button vertical-button-right" value=@(Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage+1)>&lsaquo;</button>

            <div class="comment-item-panel">

                @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
                {
                    <div class="comment-item">
                        <h5>@comment.Commentator.UserName</h5>
                        <p>@comment.Text</p>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>

                <button type="submit" name="page" class="vertical-button vertical-button-left" value=@(Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage-1)>&rsaquo;</button>

        }


        .comment-item-panel {
            right: 999em;
            transition: right 1s;


 }
```

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: @smoksnes I prefer plain javascript but I think the context is the same. so it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess doesn't make the CSS tranisition to work - try this

http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2013/09/part-95-onbegin-oncomplete-onsuccess.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's more of an work-around to maybe help you on your way.

If `show()` is triggered before the contents is rendered you can listen to the dom-manipulation.

Someting like this:

```
function show() {
   // Listen to dom manipulation, and trigger when items added.
    $("form").one("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
        alert("tree changed");
        document.getElementsByClassName("comment-item-panel")[0].style.right = 0;
    });

}
```

Snippet below is more of a proof-of-concept of the dom-manipulation part.

```js
// Only occur once, since it's rebound every post.
$("#comments").one("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});

$('button').click(function(){
 $("#comments").append('<p>new element added!</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comments">
  
</div>
<button>Add Element</button>
```